# Load screen on page reload();

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have a small Phonegap app and on a button click I have it refresh the page via:

window.location.reload();

It loads pretty fast. However, although fast, you can see a flash of some elements being loaded before others. I would like to do some sort of load screen during this time, which I think will be a nice touch.

What might be the best way for me to do this? It wouldn't be at application start, but somehow tied into the button that calls for the page to be refreshed.

BTW, I am not using Jquery Mobile or Zepto .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too privy on phonegap but I believe it is just normal HTML, CSS and JS no? So then why not just have an [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that grabs your data, so the page itself is not actually refreshed but the data within the container. Then just have a div [prepended](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to the body on the refresh call that contains your loader information (spinning gif, loading, etc). Then disappears on the ajax callback.

Comment: This is a locally run app.